# How does bitmap image change in pressed and released?

Tags: c++, qt, bitmap

This is the code using Qt 4 to change the image bitmap when pressing and releasing a `QPushButton`:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_pressed()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose"), "", tr("images (*.bmp)"));

    if(QString::compare(filename, QString()) != 0)
    {
        QImage image;
        bool volid = image.load(filename);

        if(volid)
        {
            ui->lineEdit->setText(filename);

            QPixmap pixmap (filename);
            QIcon ButtonIcon (pixmap);
            ui->pushButton->setIcon(ButtonIcon);
            ui->pushButton->setAutoRepeat(true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Error handling
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_released()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose"), "", tr("images (*.bmp)"));

    if(QString::compare(filename, QString()) != 0)
    {
        QImage image;
        bool volid = image.load(filename);

        if(volid)
        {
            ui->lineEdit_2->setText(filename);

            QPixmap pixmap (filename);
            QIcon ButtonIcon (pixmap);
            ui->pushButton->setIcon(ButtonIcon);
            ui->pushButton->setAutoRepeat(false);
        }
        else
        {
            // Error handling
        }
    }
}
```

The picture below shows that I need select two images and add to button actions to be changed in pressing and releasing.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is your question ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a hover button which changes image when mouse is over button, or it has a different image for pressed down state

Comment: @SGaist the question is in the title. How does bitmap image change in pressed and released?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani actually, I need to change the bitmap based on the click and release not hover. I want to change the code to work like that.